Laravel Socialite randomly missing 'code' in request
I'm using Laravel Socialite in my project for google login.
    public function handleProviderCallback(): RedirectResponse
    {
       $provider = Socialite::driver('google')->scopes(['openid', 'email']);
       $provider->redirectUrl(URL('oauth/google/callback'));
       $oAuthUser = $provider->stateless()->user();

the above method works fine most of the time, but every once in a while i get an error
Client error: POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token resulted in a 400 Bad Request response: { "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "Missing required parameter: code" }
I'm unable to reproduce this in local. please me to figure out how to fix this ?
->scopes(['openid', 'email'])

was later added to fix this but failed to fix it.

Could it be cases where users have declined the authorization? In that case, they'd be redirected back to your redirect URI without a code parameter in the URL - and if the logic that follows doesn't correctly check for that, but makes the POST request anyway ...

@CBroe Thanks for the help, but this is not the issue. any other case may cause this ?

Haven't seen the code that actually tries to exchange the code for a token, but it sounds as if there has been no proper validation implemented, whether that parameter actually existed.
